# Arduino print commands

Tags: printing, wifi, arduino

I am currently connecting my [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) with the Wi-Fi [shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoShields) and everything is going great. Where does the print commands (such as `WiFi.localIP()` or `Serial.print()` ) print?

I searched and can't find them. I try to access with my web browser to my [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address), but nothing's working.

Answer (score 2):

`Serial.print()` will print to the serial interface regardless of whether the Wi-Fi shield is connected or not. This is particularly useful for debugging. These characters WILL NOT go out over the Wi-Fi connection.

To print characters to a connected WiFi client (when using the Arduino as a server), look at the example *[Wi-Fi Web Server](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebServer)*.

Notice how the HTTP response is built up line by line. If you're trying to connect to your Arduino through your web browser, you can follow the format in the example and replace it with the necessary text or HTML you want to see in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this example before. Like I said,  I have no problems connecting to the WiFi, my problem is that I don't know what http adress I to put on my browser to see the print results.

I tried my ip, etc. but nothing's working.

Thanks again.

Comment: `http://192.168.1.1` or whatever IP should just work. Try it with the Arduino connected via USB and the Serial Monitor open. Look at the debugging lines and make sure it connects to the network and is getting the IP you think it's getting.

Comment: Also make sure you're connecting on the right port. If you started the server on anything other than port 80, for example 8080, you'll need to use `http://192.168.1.1:8080` in the browser.